# How to configure custom AtmosphereResource in Atmosphere framework

Tags: java, websocket, configuration, comet, atmosphere

Unable to configure Atmosphere to use custom `AtmosphereResource` instead of `AtmosphereResourceImpl`. I have tried to use `init-param` in Servlet configuration as defined below but it is not working.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sample.MyAtmosphereResource</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this problem is already available in atmosphere. Since the API documentation is mostly focused on how do a sample application these kind of features are not discussed properly in their documentation.

Following link has some Atmosphere annotations which can do some awesome things.
http://async-io.org/apidocs/index.html?org/atmosphere/config/service/package-summary.html

Answer for this question is,
Create a factory by implementing `AtmosphereResourceFactory` which creates Custom AtmosphereResource objects and annotate the factory as `@AtmosphereResourceFactoryService`. Thats all. Now you can see that the custom AtmosphereResource resource is passed to `AtmosphereHandler`.